# Using functions repeatedly instead of variables

Tags: performance

I think I know the answer already but I would like some clarification on what exactly is happening in the back end.

Usually I call a wordpress function such as `get_post_meta($id)` and assign it to a variable if I wish to reuse it later on. What kind of performance hit would happen if I used `get_post_meta($id)` over and over again instead of the variable, say in an if statement or in a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is going to be pretty minimal, I'd expect.

There is overhead to using the functions, which you could save by storing your output in a variable.  (WordPress does a pretty good job at caching the queries though.)

And the variable is going to be more convenient as it is probably fewer characters than the function.

A drawback to using a variable is that code will not be able to hook into the functions if that code runs after you've saved the value to the variable, so that could potentially cause trouble.

I am going to answer "you probably don't need to worry about performance but there are other things to think about".